# What is the function definition for member?

Tags: scheme

```
(define (member atom list)
  (cond
    ((null? list) '())
    (= atom (car list) "True")
      (else
      (member atom(cdr list)))
    )
 )

(member '5 '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Always it gives true even though that atom isn't a member in the list. Could you plz help me to clarify this question as soon as possible.

Comment: What would be if you pass `(member '6 '(1 2 3 4 5))` ?

Comment: Take a close look at the second case in the cond expression. What's the predicate and what's the consequent?

Answer (score 2):

The second clause of `cond` should be:

```
((= atom (car list)) "True")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I missed a bracket.. This helped me lot!